# 29" Ascension mountain bike by Schwinn

Tags: freewheel

My freewheel stopped working. I can still pedal forward, but not backward. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.  Please use the search functions before asking questions... many already have good answers.  When typing your question, Stack Exchange also offers possibly helpful links to existing questions.  Your question "29" Ascension mountain bike by Schwinn" has little to do with your actual question.  If you'd entered something about  "freewheel not working" you'd see a lot of useful questions plus answers.   As it stands this question is likely to be closed as a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a freewheel (which it seems like you have on the BSO), and theres anything wrong with it, the solution is to [replace it](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/cassette-and-freewheel-removal-and-installation#article-section-6) (if those directions don't work, you can try [this method](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/freewheel-destructive-removal)). In general, they're not user serviceable parts.

My guess is that you have some pawls stuck or something.  A stopgap measure that might work is dumping wd-40 or similar into/around the freewheel.

In any case, the repair will be the same -- buy a new freewheel, a freewheel remover tool and install a new freewheel on.

Answer (score 0):

The freewheel is not that expensive for that bike--around $11 + S&H from many online retailers.

Your LBS can do the swap for you--just bring them the rear wheel and the replacement Freewheel and expect to pay for about 30 mins of labor.  You could also buy a replacement rear wheel that comes with a freewheel... but that would probably be more expensive.

Depending on the age of the bike, call the manufacturer--have the model# and serial# handy-- and they may send you one for free or reduced cost--you'll still have to pay the LBS or purchase a [Typical Freewheel Removal tool](http://www.parktool.com/product/freewheel-remover-fr-1-2).

[And here is where to start with Schwinn Tech support](http://www.schwinnbikes.com/usa/support/faq)

The LBS will also usually have a freewheel removal tool for purchase as well.